# SED - Substituir por variável com caracteres especiais

Tags: linux, sed

Tenho um arquivo .sh que faz a substituição de algumas palavras em um arquivo .yml por variaveis que informo no comando docker run, porém duas dessas variaveis tem caracteres especial "/".

Para resolver troquei o separador da sintaxe por ";", no meu terminal isso funciona, porém quando rodo a saída do docker run, ele não substitui.

sed -i -e "s;PALAVRA;${VARIAVEL};g" arquivo.yml

VARIAVEL = palavra/palavra/palavra

Comment: tenta     sed -i -e "s;PALAVRA;{echo $VARIA|VEL|sed -i s/\// \\\//g};g" arquivo.yml

Comment: Funcionou, tirando as "{" antes da variavel e colocando  "$PALAVRA".
A sintaxe final ficou:  
    sed -i -e "s;PALAVRA;$VARIAVEL;g" arquivo.yml
Muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Funcionou, tirando as "{" antes da variavel e colocando "$PALAVRA". A sintaxe final ficou: sed -i -e "s;PALAVRA;$VARIAVEL;g" arquivo.yml

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).